# Should there be a link between the class name and the file name in which it resides?

Tags: objective-c

OK, so I have 2 files (header and implementation) named `MyLib.h` and `MyLib.m`, inside those 2 files I have multiple classes, protocols and interfaces but none called 'MyLib'. Now, everything works just fine, I have only one problem, xCode doesn't show me any class hint except for `MyLib` (which btw is only the name of the file, there is no `MyLib` class).

Now, this small problem made me think about it, is this a bad practice? Is is better to have a file for each class and if yes, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a `.h` file with a different name from the class inside it, and Xcode gives me the completion for the class name, not the file name. Have you `#import`ed the header wherever you're trying to use it?

Comment: argh...I can't believe it works now. OK, probably there was another error in the project and it was confused. My bad. So I take it that this is a common practice?

Comment: I don't think it's *very* common, but it's certainly okay. I've definitely seen some implementation files with multiple classes inside them (private classes, etc.) as well.